# I've forced a site to use HTTPS but now there is ?url=/ in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I've used the .HTACCESS file to force a website to use HTTPS. I did it the following way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, when you go to uv-technik.co.uk although it does force HTTPS it comes up like this in the URL - https://www.uv-technik.co.uk/?url=/

How can I get rid of the ?url=/

Comment: Make sure this is your top most rule

Comment: Nothing in what you have shown can explain how `?url=` arrived in the final URL, so you have other rules in your configuration and you need to kook at them globally. Tip: put things like that in main Apache configuration file if you can, instead of `.htaccess` files as you will then gain: simplicity, performance and security.

Answer (score 0):

I have done so, and it works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://your_url/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.